# Exercise 2.11 of Waterhouse about Hopf algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra, hopf-algebras, group-schemes

I asked part (c) of this exercise already in this link [Categorization of Group Scheme of rank 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3960253/categorization-of-group-scheme-of-rank-2). But I still have some difficulty solving next parts of this exercise. So I hope anyone can help me to clear it out. Thank you

> Let $A$ be a Hopf algebra over $k$ (a base ring) which is free of rank 2. I proved that $I = Ker(\epsilon) = kx$ for some $x$, and $\Delta(x) = x \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes x + b x\otimes x$ for some $b$ in k. Also, $x^2 + ax = 0$ for some $a$, and $A = k[X]/(X^2 + aX)$.
> (d) Use $\Delta(x^2) = (\Delta x)^2$ to show $(2 - ab)^2=2-ab$.
> (e) Show $Sx = cx$ with $c^2 = 1$. Then use (e) and $0 = (S, id)\Delta x$ to show $c = 1$ and $ab = 2$.

For part (d), after replacing the expression of $\Delta x$ into $\Delta(x^2) = (\Delta x)^2$, I got $ax(2-ab)^2 = ax(2-ab)$. Because $1, x$ is a basis of $A$, so we must have $a(2-ab)^2 = a(2-ab)$. But because $k$ may be not an integral domain, so $a$ can be a zerodivisor. In this case, I can't conclude that $(2-ab)^2 = (2-ab)$.

For part (e), the fact that $Sx = cx$ for some $c^2=1$ seems to imply that $S^2 = id$, which is not stated in the book of Waterhouse. But in the book Algebraic Groups of Milne, Exercise 3.3 (a), it states that $S^2=id$. The difference between the two definitions is, the definition of Waterhouse assumes $k$ is a general ring, while the definition of Milne assumes $k$ is a field. So, is this relation always true for all Hopf algebra? And if not, is it always true in case $k$ is a field? Thank a lot for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$\begin{align*}
\Delta(x^2) &= \Delta(-ax) = -a \Delta(x) \\ 
&= -a (x \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes x + b x \otimes x), \\
\Delta(x)^2 &= (x \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes x + b x \otimes x)^2 \\
&= x^2 \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes x^2 + b^2 x^2 \otimes x^2 + 2 x \otimes x + 2b x^2 \otimes x + 2b x \otimes x^2 \\
&= -ax \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes ax + a^2 b^2 x \otimes x + 2 x \otimes x - 2ab x \otimes x - 2ab x \otimes x \\
&= -a(x \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes x) + (2 - 4ab + a^2 b^2)(x \otimes x).
\end{align*}$$

Equating the coefficients of $x \otimes x$, we have $$-ab = 2 - 4ab + a^2 b^2.$$  Simplifying, we have
$$\begin{align*}
0 &= (ab)^2 - 3ab + 2 \\
&= (2 - ab)(1 - ab) \\
&= (2 - ab)((2 - ab) - 1 \\
&= (2-ab)^2 - (2-ab),
\end{align*}$$
so that $(2-ab)^2 = 2 - ab$ as desired.

For the rest of the question, a Hopf algebra for which $S^2 = \mathrm{id}$ is called *involutive*. Not all Hopf algebras are involutive (even over a field), but there are general conditions that would imply that a Hopf algebra is involutive.  Googling this word will probably turn up more references.

Comment: Thank you. I got the first part of your answer . Related to the second question, I guess what I want to ask is, how the definition of Waterhouse and Milne implies that their Hopf algebras are involutile, while the other definition doesn't. What is the implicit assumption which makes it the case?

Comment: I don't have access to the books you mentioned, so I can't help you there.

Comment: The book is available online here (https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/iAG200.pdf). The definition of Hopf algebra is in page 56, and in Exercise 3.2(a), it states that S^2 = id. I hope you can take a look. I'm really grateful in advance.

Comment: That exercise seems to deal with Hopf algebras that are obtained as functions on an algebraic group - in that case it is clear that $S^2 = \mathrm{id}$ since the inverse of the inverse of an element in a group is the element itself.  More generally, functions on an algebraic group form a commutative Hopf algebra, and commutative Hopf algebras are involutive.

Comment: Ah yes, I think commutivity is the implicit reason why these Hopf algebra is involutive. Thanks a lot for your help.